# Threejs blending with opacity

Tags: three.js

I want to use `THREE.AdditiveBlending` and `THREE.SubtractiveBlending` blending on a material that I am fading onto a scene.

Eg:

```
fieldFader.material.blending = THREE.SubtractiveBlending
fieldFader.material.color = new THREE.Color(colorInverse3)
fieldFader.material.opacity = 0
await tweenOpacity(fieldFader.material, { opacity: 1 }, timeToTween)
```

*Note: the tweenOpacity function simply tweens the opacity of the material from 0 to 1 over time `timeToTween` and is updated in my render loop*

However, when I do this, at the point of starting (0 opacity), I DESIRE to for NO BLENDING to take place, then as I tween the opacity to 1, then 100% of the blending subtraction would be applied.

See the pictures for an example:[image: blending example]

It would be great if I could be pointed in the right direction as to how to achieve this, but also to better understanding the problem so I can code with it for effectively.

One option that I will look at it so tween the colours rather than the opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to tween the colors and opacity:

```
fieldFader.material.blending = THREE.SubtractiveBlending
fieldFader.material.color = new THREE.Color(targetColor)
fieldFader.material.opacity = 0

let meta = { opacity: 0, r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }

await tweenOpacity(m, {
  opacity: 1,
  r: targetR,
  g: targetG,
  b: targetB
}, timeToTween)
```

Where the tween function would update the color and opacity in the `.onUpdate()` callback.

```
fieldFader.material.opacity = from.opacity
fieldFader.material.color = new THREE.Color(`rgb(${Math.floor(from.r)},${Math.floor(from.g)},${Math.floor(from.b)})`)
```

*Note: For some reason, nested tweens on a THREE.js material didn't work so I directly updated the material from the tweened meta object*